# I have to extract the two epoch time from the data and then i have to find difference between them in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have this data where i have two epoch value and i have to extract the value and then need to calculate there difference?

```
;;epoch1;;epoch 2 
617B96A302C71177;;1638297252.658;;1638297253.078;TTrans1;DEE61;66500;xxxxx;in;0x19;0x0;0;;scb:in;0x19;0x0;0;;sc:iund;0x0;ggp-ir:djkoe:ID 0: DSP: 1:trunk_02:ch_000
```

I tried below method but don't know how to calculate the difference.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F";;|;" -vOFS='\t' '{print strftime("%c", $3),  strftime("%c", $2)}' duration.txt(data is written in this file)
```

---

Output of above command:-
Wed Dec  1 00:04:13 2021    Wed Dec  1 00:04:12 2021
Wed Dec  1 00:03:46 2021    Wed Dec  1 00:03:23 2021

---

epoch 1 =1638297252.658 epoch2 = 1638297253.078 first I have to extract the epochs value from the mentioned string. And then to calculate the time gap (or difference), I am trying to convert it into below format

Wednesday 01 December 2021 12:04:13 AM IST .

But even after converting both epoch in mentioned format i don't know what to do for calculating difference.

And I have used the awk command to extract the field from the string.
please excuse my poor explanation

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please mention samples of input and samples of expected output more clearly in your question(edit your question), thank you.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment here).

Comment: @NamanSharma, As mentioned in above comments, please do update your question with all information, comments are not meant to put info, thank you.

Comment: Thank you @RavinderSingh13. I have made the changes.

Comment: Both time stamps refer to November 30. How do you calculate the 1st of December?

Comment: @Cyrus I have used strftime("%c", $3) function in awk command.

and also tried the date command still getting the 1st December
date -d@1638297253.078

Comment: Okay, maybe that's because of the different time zones.

Comment: yes mine is IST.

Comment: The difference is 420 milliseconds. It doesn't make sense to use a full human readable date format. Do you just want to subtract the lower date from the higher date, for a result in seconds? Rounded to whole second? Or three decimal places (milliseconds)? Is the second one always higher? Or may either one be higher?

Comment: Hi @dan , yes I just want to subtract the lower date from higher..

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
$ awk -F";" '{$3=strftime("%A %d %B %Y %T %Z",$3); $5=strftime("%A %d %B %Y %T %Z",$5); hour=substr($3,17,2);min=substr($3,20,2);sec=substr($3,23,2); hour2=substr($5,17,2);min2=substr($5,20,2);sec2=substr($5,23,2)} NR > 1 {print "epoch 1: "$3"\nepoch 2: "$5"\nTime difference is "hour2 - hour" hours " min2-min" minutes " sec2 - sec" seconds"}' input_file
epoch 1: Tuesday 30 November 2021 18:34:12 GMT
epoch 2: Tuesday 30 November 2021 18:34:13 GMT
Time difference is 0 hours 0 minutes 1 seconds
```

```
$ cat script.awk
#!/usr/bin/env/ awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=";"
} {
    $3=strftime("%A %d %B %Y %T %Z",$3)
    $5=strftime("%A %d %B %Y %T %Z",$5)
    hour=substr($3,26,2)
    min=substr($3,29,2)
    sec=substr($3,32,2)
    hour2=substr($5,26,2)
    min2=substr($5,29,2)
    sec2=substr($5,32,2)
} NR > 1 {
    print "epoch 1: "$3"\nepoch 2: "$5"\nTime difference is "hour2 - hour" hours " min2-min" minutes " sec2 - sec" seconds"
}
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk input_file
epoch 1: Tuesday 30 November 2021 18:34:12 GMT
epoch 2: Tuesday 30 November 2021 18:34:13 GMT
Time difference is 0 hours 0 minutes 1 seconds
```

Comment: I have used ;; as a delimiter. And there is multiple line in txt file. But this script only showing one output.

Comment: @NamanSharma The script will not work if you use `;;` as the delimiter. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ';' 'FNR!=1 {high = $3>$5?$3:$5; low = $3<$5?$3:$5; print high-low}' duration.txt

# gives
0.42
```

Or perhaps more readably:

```
awk -F ';' '
FNR!=1 {
    if ($3 > $5) {
        high=$3; low=$5
    } else {
        high=$5; low=$3
    }
    print high-low
}' duration.txt
```